# Why do I have more 'originals' than 'versions' in Aperture?

Tags: apple-aperture

In Aperture, when I open the 'Switch to Library' menu, it reports that my library has '797 versions, 1802 originals'.

If I open the 'Photos' tab, there are indeed 797 items. So what are the 'originals'?

Is this remnant of something that haven't been cleaned up properly when I have deleted images from the library?

The 'Switch to Library' menu is found from the 'File |> Switch To Library |> Other/New...". When selecting a library, it shows the versions/originals statistics in the bottom of the dialog. Though, sometimes it doesn't show for the currently loaded library, so you have to switch to a different library first.

Comment: Where do you see this "797 versions, 1802 originals" information?  I am not seeing that in Aperture 3.4.5 on MacOSX 10.8.

Comment: @khedron - I updated the question with the information. But I'm running 3.5.1 - so there could be differences there

Comment: Aha!  Thanks.  I had to create a new library to switch to in order to see what you were seeing.  Yes, I have 70267 versions, 70398 originals.  Emptying the Aperture trash did not change that.  It's not the number of videos (I have more than 131).  In fact, after deleting all rejected items & emptying trash, the delta is now 169!  And showing "all photos" only shows 70077 items (including videos).  So: I don't know.  I thought for a moment that perhaps a "version" was only created if there was any processing done, but then you would expect to see more than 797 photos in your library.

Comment: Was this answered by your "images were in shared services" comment on another post?  FB / Photo Stream?

Comment: @khedron - no this was not answered by the "shared services" - but I think it's related. I think it's an Aperture bug, that it's counting some images that have been shared, but no longer is.